# Create 2 new columns using parts of the filename for a csv file

Tags: linux, csv, awk, command-line

I've managed to work out how to get my filename into my file as an additional column but can't work out how to strip out the unnecessary parts of the filename and place the parts I do want, into additional columns.

**Example Filenames**

```
20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
20191002_export_format_client_platform.csv
20190928_export_format_client_platform.csv
```

the `export_format` part remains exactly the same on all files. The only thing that changes is the date at the start of the name, the client name and their platform name

**Input csv data**

```
visitor_date,browser,id1,id2,id3
30/09/2019 00:00,69246,216370,411751188
30/09/2019 00:00,69247,216370,411751188
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411511576
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751576
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751170
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751152
```

**My attempted script**

```
awk '{ print $0 FILENAME }' *.csv > *.csv
```

**My attempted output**

```
visitor_date,id1,id2,id3,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:00,69246,216370,411751188,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:00,69247,216370,411751188,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411511576,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751576,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751170,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751152,20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
```

**Desired Output**

```
visitor_date,id1,id2,id3,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:00,692467,2163703,4117511887,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:00,692467,2163703,4117511887,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,692467,2163703,4117511576,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,692467,2163703,4117511576,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,692467,2163703,4117511780,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,692467,2163704,4117511528,client,platform
```

So from the filename I should only take the bolded parts of the file name: 20191001_export_format_**client**_**platform**.csv, which should then become 2 new columns

Is there a tidy way to do this within `awk` or would I need to use a different command to achieve the result? Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Use [`split`](https://www.poftut.com/awk-text-split-delimit-examples/) to split the `FILENAME` on `_`. Then just  print the `$0` with a comma and proper elements after split.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the feedback. Realised I was mistaking the awk split you are proposing for the `split` command. I'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: @KamilCuk unfortunately I can't seem to get the split command to work. Can you confirm if there is something wrong with the script I am trying to use? `cat 20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv | awk '{split(FILENAME,a,"_"); print $0, a[4] a[5] }'`

My thought process here is to list the file and then pipe that in where I can split the `FILENAME` and then combine the file with the `print` command. But this is clearly off the mark.

Comment: But `awk` has to know about the FILENAME. Do `awk .... 20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv`. If you `cat` to `awk`, `awk` will not know the filename - will only see the lines. Also, for a comma, just concatenate `print $0 "," a[4] "," a[5]`.  The `,` in `print` will be substituted for `OFS`. Arg, there is a `.` on the end, we need to remove it too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something along:

```
awk '{ split(FILENAME, a, "_"); split(a[5], b, ".");  print $0 "," a[4] "," b[1] }' 20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
```

For input:

```
cat <<EOF >20191001_export_format_client_platform.csv
visitor_date,browser,id1,id2,id3
30/09/2019 00:00,69246,216370,411751188
30/09/2019 00:00,69247,216370,411751188
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411511576
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751576
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751170
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751152
EOF
```

It will output:

```
visitor_date,browser,id1,id2,id3,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:00,69246,216370,411751188,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:00,69247,216370,411751188,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411511576,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751576,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751170,client,platform
30/09/2019 00:14,69246,216370,411751152,client,platform
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    FNR == 1 {
        f = FILENAME
        sub(/\.csv$/, "", f)
        n = split(f, a, /_/)

        client = a[n-1]
        platform = a[n]

        if (out) close(out)
        out = f "-out.csv"
    }
    { print $0, client, platform > out }
' *.csv
```